# QSlider coloring in PyQt5 Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, slider

I would like to set different color to a specific range on the QSlider, in Python programming language. So for example I have a slider that has value from 0 to 100. And I have an area, maybe more, like between 30 and 50.

I can't find anything about this on the internet, does anyone have a solution for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you want to use the default style appearance, you need to subclass QSlider and override its `paintEvent()`, then customize the painting using QStyle functions. It's doable, but requires a bit of experience with both painting and QStyle, so I suggest to start your research about these topics. A possible hint: look at the official Qt sources and how QSlider implements `paintEvent()`, then check what the different subcontrols cause with painting.